# Add image to data-original-title

Tags: html, tooltip

I'm trying to add an image to the `data-original-title` attribute. Any ideas how to achieve this? It is for a tooltip popup.

```
<span class="tooltips">
    <a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Add Tooltips everywhere! Nice, huh? <img src='http://www.url.com/imagelink.jpg'>">Anchor Test</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

That I believe is not possible. However, it appears that you are trying to have images in a tooltip made of an anchor. There are alternatives to do just that. For instance, you can use [jQuery's tooltip preview plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/Easy-Tooltip-Image-Preview-Plugin-with-jQuery.html).